# Android Kotlin UI Async Http request - AsyncTask or Custom Libraries?

Tags: android, http, asynchronous, android-asynctask, kotlin

Specifically trying do some non-blocking http operations within a UI context.

1. I read up on **coroutines** whicch blew my tiny mind, couldn't work out how to invoke a declarative *suspend* method from a UI event.
2. Had a fair crack with **AsyncTask** in conjunction with **URL(addr).openStream()**, which seemed ok, but I couldn't seem find any good examples where a lambda was being passed in for the oncomplete processing. All the examples seemed to just directly name the control instances in the in the **onPostExecute** function.

I was keen to find a more reusable pattern, perhaps in the styley of jquery's ajax pattern.

3. The **Fuel** http client library seems pretty good, I've knocked this together which seems to do the trick:

   ```
   val url_public_ip: String = "http://ipinfo.io/json"
   val url_fake_data: String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos"

   fun btnGetPublicIp_Click(view: View){
       getData(url_public_ip, txtData) 
   }

   fun btnGetMockData_Click(view: View){
       getData(url_fake_data, txtData) 
   }

   fun getData(url: String, control: TextView){
       control.text = "Querying..."

       // Fuel based async request.
       url.httpGet().responseString { request, response, result ->
           when (result) {
               is Result.Failure -> {
                   var error: String? = result.getAs()

                   control.text = error
               }
               is Result.Success -> {
                   var data: String? = result.getAs()

                   control.text = data
               }
           }
       } 
   }
   ```

So, the question:

Is anyone else using other custom libs to do this & what kinda stuff are you guys using?